# Using anchor tags in VueJS Swiper

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

This is in reference to a project using VueJS 2.0 and Swiper v8.3.2

If I had a swiperSlide that looks similar to this:

```
<template>
  <a
    :href="url"
    :title="title"
  >{{ title }}</a>
</template>
```

How would I enable a click-through to _self, _target etc.?  The click is being captured by Swiper, even adding a @click function won't work.

Comment: Try `@click.native="handlerMethod"`

Comment: No joy :( .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
@click.prevent="handlerMethod"
@keydown.enter.prevent="handlerMethod"
```